# In WinRT, why does calling Task.Result from a synchronous context block my app

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime

I'm involved in porting some code over to a Windows Store Library.
It would be convenient for us to be able to sometimes wait for the results of an asynchronous operation before continuing. I thought we had the answer with Task's Result property, but for some reason it crashes my app.

I made a quick Windows Store test App like so:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyTextBox.Text = "0";
    var a = ReturnIntMax();
    MyTextBox.Text = "1";
    MyTextBox.Text = a.Result.ToString();
}

public async Task<int> ReturnIntMax()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return 5;
}
```

As far as I understand the Result property, this should work, so I hope somebody can tell me what's going on. I'm not interested in why this is bad design. We're dealing with a lot of comm traffic and we can't allow conflicts. If necessary, we can work around this, but first I want to understand why its not working. If it's just unsupported to call Result from a synchronous context, I would have thought it would give me a compiler error.

Comment: http://blog.filipekberg.se/2013/04/03/dont-deadlock-with-async-and-await/ **or** http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @Kiewic of course. OP's asking why the code blocks, not how to fix it.

Comment: The issue with `SynchronizationContext` is described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I describe the [underlying cause of the deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) on my blog. This is not a compiler error for several reasons; e.g., it's a violation of separation of concerns to ask a compiler (which is responsible for translating C# to IL) to understand the threading models of various user interface frameworks. Also, it's not practical to add an error for each call to `Result` that *might* be on a UI thread.

As a general rule, do not use `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result` at all. Instead, find a way to structure your code so that it's asynchronous. This can be awkward, but in the end you'll find that you end up with a better UI design (i.e., instead of blocking the UI while the main page loads, you need to design a blank or "loading..." page that can be shown immediately and then transition to show the data). My blog posts on [constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) and [properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) have some ideas on how to make them `async`-friendly.

Comment: The way the code was originally structured, there were two threads, one for the UI and one for the logic dealing with all the comm traffic. For the most part its important that the comm traffic thread run synchronously, which it seems will involve peppering the code with await commands.